# How to set the xticks for the end of the month

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, datetime-format, xticks

I have a list of dates that fall on the end of each month, and I would like for the gridlines and labels of my plot to coincide with these dates. Currently I can only get the chart to plot at the beginning of the month. Is there a way to force Matplotlib to use the end of month values in its charting?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
  
dts = [datetime(2020, 11, 30), datetime(2020, 12, 31),
           datetime(2021, 1, 31), datetime(2021, 2, 28),
           datetime(2021, 3, 31), datetime(2021, 4, 30),
           datetime(2021, 5, 31), datetime(2021, 6, 30),
           datetime(2021, 7, 31), datetime(2021, 8, 31),
           datetime(2021, 9, 30), datetime(2021, 10, 31),
           datetime(2021, 11, 30), datetime(2021, 12, 31),
           datetime(2022, 1, 31), datetime(2022, 2, 28),]
vals = [2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 4500, 4000, 3000, 2500, 4000, 4500, 3000, 
             2500, 6000, 4000, 3000, 5000]
    
figsize=(3, 6)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator((3, 6, 9, 12)))
fmt = DateFormatter("%Y-%m")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

ax.plot(dts, vals, color = 'blue')
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is just to manually or dynamically `set_ticks()` with:

```
ax.set_xticks([datetime(2020, 12, 31), datetime(2021, 3, 31), datetime(2021, 6, 30), datetime(2021, 9, 30), datetime(2021, 12, 31)])
```

OR Better:

```
ax.set_xticks(dts[1::3]) # this uses every third element starting with second element
```

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

fmt = DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
ax.set_xticks([datetime(2020, 12, 31), datetime(2021, 3, 31), datetime(2021, 6, 30), datetime(2021, 9, 30), datetime(2021, 12, 31)])
ax.set_xticks(dts[1::3])

ax.plot(dts, vals, color = 'blue')
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- The correct option, which doesn't require creating a list of `datetime` objects, is to set `bymonthday=-1` in [`mdates.MonthLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator).

  - [Setting xticks to the first day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76963853/7758804)
- [`matplotlib.dates API`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html)
- This is also applicable to [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) and [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas).

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

ax.plot(dts, vals)

fmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=range(3, 13, 3), bymonthday=-1))

ax.grid(True)
```

[image]