# Setting xticks to the first day of the month

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, datetime-format, xticks

I´m practicing seaborn visualization with a database created from scratch.
The point is that I want to see the data from this stock market prices visualizing only the first day of the month but the steps that it has are irregular: How can I indicate it to .xticks()?
I leave you what I´ve done:

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Create a sample dataset
np.random.seed(42)
num_entries = 100

start_date = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
date_list = [start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(num_entries)]
prices = np.random.uniform(50, 200, num_entries)
volumes = np.random.randint(1000, 10000, num_entries)
returns = np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, num_entries)

data = {
    "Date": date_list,
    "Price": prices,
    "Volume": volumes,
    "Returns": returns
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Plotting

```
sns.lineplot( x = "Date", y = "Price", data = df)
plt.title("Evolution of prices along time")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.xticks(ticks =np.arange(0,101,step=31))
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib.dates` has [`mdates`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html) module to achieve this. First, you need to define the `xticks` with a month frequency. After that, you can edit the `xticklabels` to also show the day of each date. Example code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Price", data=df)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- To have the `%d` component, set the `xtick` format, and specify `bymonthday` in [`mdates.MonthLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator) to the actual day for the major tick, where `-1` will produce the last day of each month. The day will not display if `DateFormatter` is not set.

  - [How to set the xticks for the end of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76963746/7758804)
  - Specify `bymonth=` for select months (e.g. `bymonth=range(3, 13, 3)`).
- [`matplotlib.dates API`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html)
- This is also applicable to [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) and [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas).

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Price", data=df)

fmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=1))
```

[image]